# Automatic Service Discovery with Eureka

Tags: java, spring, service, netflix-eureka

is there a possibility to automatically discover services with Eureka? What I want to do is to have a service "Collect" which accepts a document. Additionally to this service there should be several other services which extract document data from the document. This could be a "TF-IDF" or a "MLT" service.

As of now I would have to change the "Collect" service each time a new data extraction service is added. This is what I would like to automate so that after adding a data extraction service it is called automatically without changing the "Collect" service.

Is there a way of achieving such an automatic service discovery or will I always have to modify the "Collect" service?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

So I found the best way to solve this problem is it to have the services providing information extraction as a  configuration. This way I can implement a loop in my Collect service and loop through each extraction service. The configuration is handles by a configuration service. This is the clostest I can come to adding services withou performing any change to the Collect service.